# StackOverflow Audience Survey

Tags: discussion, advertising, stack-overflow-developer-survey

Is [this](http://inedomedia.com/stackoverflowsurvey.aspx) for real?

Comment: I tried taking it but I found it wasn't very well thought out.. The very first question just assumes I work in a company. I bet a considerable percentage of us are students, do this for a hobby, are unemployed or are self employed. Assuming that every single person that takes the survey works for a company is ridiculous.

Comment: It is, however, absolutely typical for this kind of survey. I guess the idea is for the ad network to be able to boast “30% of our users make purchasing decisions for companies of 500 employees!” which sounds great to advertisers. They don't want the students and one-man-banders messing up those stats!

Comment: Oh, just to be clear, I didn’t mean the question as a complaint — I just wasn’t entirely sure the survey was actually affiliated with Stack Overflow, as I hadn’t heard anything about a survey, and it seemed a little odd to link to the survey from an advert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's something Alex / Inedo did, and they are our official advertising partners.

Check the survey tag

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/survey

for prior questions on this topic